# CSS: Place footer always at the bottom

Tags: html, css, position

I have following page layout:

```
<header></header>
<div id="content"></div>
<aside></aside>
<footer>
 <ul>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</footer>
```

Now I want to place the footer exactly in the left corner:

```
text-align: left;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
margin: -16px -8px;
```

Now is the negative margin not the best solution.
Are there better ways to positionate a footer directly in the corner?

Regards

Comment: What browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/wyrju/ cuts the test text on chrome. Without the negative margin it's fine.

Comment: there was a mistake in mapping (margin between footer and footer ul)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

write like this:

```
text-align: left;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left:0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you this helps. Unfortunatly I have another issue:
When I set width and padding to the footer, than the li's aren't in a line but under each other. If I set width and padding to footer ul it's fine..

Comment: Hi,solved already. Forgot to fix the margin/padding of a child element :)

Answer (score 7):

Check this site [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

**Example:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for me it works like this:

```
height: 58px;
position:relative;
bottom: -58px;
```

Note the same value for `height` and `bottom`. And the `postion` to `relative`.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```